# How to use the Visual Studio Code *CLI* to Remote-Container Attach to a running Container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers

I am looking for a way to open Visual Studio Code using the CLI and attach it directly to a container running instead of using GUI.

[image: Attach]

Example:

```
vscode <my-running-container>
```

Thanks:)